# Automatically import new csv file data into a "Database" Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv, powerquery

**My situation:**
At a competition, we will have 6 "scorers" each using a separate android tablet.  For every game (there will probably be 70 or 80 throughout the tournament), each person will score accordingly on a custom app that will create a .csv file. (To be clear, each match will result in 6 separate, 1 row, csv files.) The format of the data will be the same from game to game, and from scorer to scorer. I can have control over the names of these files such as "[Scorer#]_[Match###].csv".  These tablets will all be connected to a central computer via USB.

**What I would like to do**:
I would like to be able to have the data from all of those files automatically populate a "database" table on a single sheet. If possible, I would like a folder to act as a "watch folder" of sorts, where, as a new file shows up in a folder, that data is automatically ingested into the table.  If that is not possible, I would be happy with a single function I could run to check for new data after each game ended.

I had considered possibly trying to use power query, but wasn't sure if that could lead me to a usable solution.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

(and I apologize if anything is unclear.  I'm happy to clear up any confusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Query is a good fit in that scenario. You can set up a query that loads all files in a specific folder and appends the contents. Refresh the query when new files have been added to the folder.

For detailed instructions how to set up such a query, take a look here:

http://excelunplugged.com/2015/02/10/get-data-from-folder-in-power-query/